# How do I code a publisher and subscriber that would send multiple lines over to the subscriber in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, chat

The example output would end up looking like:

Client Side:

Enter new command: B50

Enter new command H70

Enter new command: Z80

Subscriber side:
Recieved: B50

Recieved: H70

Recieved: Z80

Current Publisher Code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket


TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
TCP_PORT = 5005
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

def sendMsg(str):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
    s.send(str.encode())
    data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    s.close()
    return

while 1:
    MESSAGE = input("Enter Command: ")
    sendMsg(MESSAGE)



print ("received data:", data.decode())
```

Current Subscriber Code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket


TCP_IP = ''
TCP_PORT = 5005
BUFFER_SIZE = 20  # Normally 1024, but we want fast response

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.listen(1)

conn, addr = s.accept()
print ('Connection address:', addr)
while 1:
    data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    if not data: break
    print ("received data:", data.decode())
    conn.send(data)  # echo
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out out, had to edit my subscriber code to this

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket


TCP_IP = ''
TCP_PORT = 5005
BUFFER_SIZE = 20  # Normally 1024, but we want fast response

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.listen(1)

conn, addr = s.accept()
print ('Connection address:', addr)
while 1:
    data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    if data: 
        print ("received data:", data.decode())
    conn.send(data)  # echo
    s.listen(1)
    conn, addr = s.accept()
conn.close()
```